# Angularjs Routing Parameter passing to controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-routing, angularjs-module

Below code is not working for parameter passing

```
   <li class="active" ng-disabled="disabledAction"><a href="#!/Reservation/821" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o icon-push"></i>{{langResources.EditReservation}}</a></li>
```

when click this link will redirecto below controller.but not getting parameter value `ie,821`

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HotelReservation(long resId = 0)
    {
        ViewBag.resId = resId;
        return PartialView();
    }

 $routeProvider.when('/Reservation/:ResId', {
    templateUrl: '/Home/HotelReservation/resId=ResId',
    controller: 'HotelReservationCtrl',
activetab: 'Reservation'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working.

code change to

```
 $routeProvider.when('/Reservation/:ResId', {
templateUrl: function (params) {
        var url='/Home/HotelReservation?resId=' + params.ResId;
         return url},    
controller: 'HotelReservationCtrl',
activetab: 'Reservation'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the when part with ?
 `$routeProvider.when('/Reservation/:ResId?', {
    templateUrl: '/Home/HotelReservation/resId=ResId',
    controller: 'HotelReservationCtrl',
activetab: 'Reservation'
});`.
As it is expecting resId parameter value in your MVC controller.
So in anchor tag do this `<a href="#!/Reservation?resId=821" >`